# Regex single quote to double quote replacing to meet json

Tags: python, regex

Please advise a general regex pattern to replace below string to be able to parse with `json.loads(string)`

`string`=

```
"""
[{'en': 'The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don't use the "Other" word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the "Mall"', 'jp': "Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa 'Lainnya'/'Other' terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa 'Mall'"}]
```

After i replace all the single quote with double quote. I am not able to find a general pattern to replace all internal double quote with single quote.
"""

Comment: Your current escaping is already incorrect. You should escape the `'` in `don't`

Comment: The error comes from `don't` If the data become like this, you can work on easily ```data = [{'en': 'The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don\'t use the "Other" word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the "Mall"', 
         'jp': 'Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa "Lainnya"/"Other" terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa "Mall"'}]```

Answer (score 1):

I added a`\` to `don\'t` to make :

```
    d = {'en': 'The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don\'t use the "Other" word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the "Mall"', 
    'jp': "Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa 'Lainnya'/'Other' terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa 'Mall'"}
```

I used replace on each value item to get rid of all double quotes and turn them to single (otherwise the output will have `\` behind each `"`:

```
    for k,v in d.items():
        d[k] = v.replace("\"","'")
```

Then I used json.dumps(d) to get it into json format:

`{"en": "The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don't use the 'Other' word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the 'Mall'", "jp": "Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa 'Lainnya'/'Other' terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa 'Mall'"}`

EDIT :

```
    import re
    
    pattern = "\""
    repl = "'"
    
    s = """[{'en': 'The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don't use the "Other" word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the "Mall"', 'jp': "Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa 'Lainnya'/'Other' terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa 'Mall'"}]"""
    
    res = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
    print(res)
```

Gives

```
    [{'en': 'The chosen word is incorrect. Please make sure you don't use the 'Other' word too often. Everything where you can buy things should be under the 'Mall'', 'jp': 'Bahasa yang dipilih salah, Pastikan anda tidak menggunakan Bahasa 'Lainnya'/'Other' terlalu sering. Semua hal dimana anda bisa membeli sesuatu harusnya menggunakan bahasa 'Mall''}]
```

Comment: sorry i have editted my question. My entire sentence is a string. I wanted to make it to json.